# Flash video works on one server, but not another

Tags: flash

I've been given a flash module to put up on our intra website. The website lives on a Microsoft IIS 6 server.  There are some slides in the module that have a frame that is supposed to be running its own embedded flash video, however the frame is blank, its just a white screen, the video they are supposed to be playing does not show up. The rest of the flash video however is running just fine.

To troubleshoot this, I've tried running the video off of my hard drive, and the whole thing works.  I've uploaded it to my own website, which is on an Apache server, and it works just fine. I've manually moved the files over to the intra site, it didn't work. I though maybe the long file names were pushing the url over it's 225 max character limit, so I shortened up the urls, that didn't work.  I've scoured the files for any weird characters, I couldn't spot any.  What other things might I try?  Why would this video play fine on one server but not another?  How else can I troubleshoot this?

Thank you for any input you have.

Answer (score 0):

When you publish the swf, do you gave the "permision" to the swf to load from the network? (publish settings->Local playback security to Access network only)